# Iframe is not working in Firefox and IE

Tags: html, grails, gsp

I am developing a application in grails which uses lot of ajax.In one part I used the following code :

```
<iframe id="hidden-upload-frame" style="border:none;height:25px;width:100%;" onload="${remoteFunction(action: 'list', controller: 'file', update: [success: 'fileDomain', failure: 'fileDomain'])}">
</iframe>

<div id="fileDomain">

</div>
```

The above code works in google chrome browser perfectly and updates fileDomain div.But in IE and firefox it opens a new window and displays the content.And it is not updating fileDomain div.How to make this work on IE and mozilla.Do I need to add doctype tag in gsp page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I corrected the code in my answer. See [Remote File upload in grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613958/remote-file-upload-in-grails/614041#614041)